# Inheriting a class will add me to queue

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a general code that will add every class that inherits from class `A`, to a queue for that specific class. So, basically it will become a node in the queue 'by itself'. All done in the constructor. No allocation necessary.

E.g., class B

```
class B: class A { // will be added to queue
    
    };
```

So will class C,

```
class C: class A { // will be added to queue
    
    };
```

My implementation so far, as simple as possible:

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
   private :
        static T* phead_; // head pointer for the first element
        T* pNext = NULL;
        T* pPrev = NULL;

   public:     

    Node(T* AddME) { addToQueue(AddME) };  // this will add the member to queue, addToQueue to use phead_
    
}


class A: public Node<A> {
    A():Node(this);

};
```

But, I am stuck with the `static` head pointer. I would like class Node to get it safely from an outside class, so whenever the constructor runs it will be already available to use?

I thought of adding another constructor, so that I get the head pointer from the class that will want to use the queue. So, I thought of adding:

```
Node(T* pHead) { phead_ = pHead; }
```

But I am afraid that it will no run on time, and the members will not get added correctly as no head will be available yet.

Also thought of adding the user of the queue to be a member of the queue - this also seems like a bad idea...

How should I proceed? Any example, idea or maybe similar implementation will help
I am working in a heap free, std:: free environment. Using C++14.

Comment: If you want to expose the private static pointer to the public, you can make a public static method that returns it. `static const T* getHead() { return phead_; }`

Comment: @paddy but then does all Node templated with type A will have the same head pointer?

Comment: Yeah. Isn't that what you want? One list for all nodes of type A?

Comment: guess so, just thinking if someone will decide to create his own list for A , it could be bad.. Thats why I am looking for a way to pass a head to it, so anyone can create his own list

Comment: If this is a re-usable generic list container, and not something purpose-built for this automatic object tracking idea of yours, then don't use a static head. You can instead define a static list in class `A`, and in the constructor for `A` you add `this` to the list. Part of your confusion comes from not actually encapsulating the concept of a list into a class. Instead, you're just relying on some raw pointer to represent your list. And it's not even a `Node<T>*`, which it probably should be instead of `T*`.